# gulp task with gulp-run-command doesn't work properly

Tags: command-line, gulp, json-server

I'm trying to run json-server in a gulp task and I'm checking if the server runs, with the function portInUse.
Like this:

```
var gulputil = require('gulp-util')
var run = require('gulp-run-command').default
var gulp = require('gulp')


const args = [
    'json-server --watch .\\src\\main\\app\\reactjs\\api\\db.json --port 3005'
]

var net = require('net');

var portInUse = function(port, callback) {
    var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
    socket.pipe(socket);
    });

    server.listen(port, '127.0.0.1');
    server.on('error', function (e) {
    callback(true);
    });
    server.on('listening', function (e) {
    server.close();
    callback(false);
    });
};

gulp.task("initLocalJsonServer", function() {
    portInUse(3005, function(returnValue) {
        gulputil.log('1 ' + returnValue);
    });

        run(args);

    portInUse(3005, function(returnValue) {
        gulputil.log('2 ' + returnValue);
    });
});
```

That command that is the value of args here, works as intended when I run it in command line, so there's nothing wrong with the command or json-server itself. If I run it, I get to see the `json-server` at `localhost:3005`

Now the output from the portInUse function indicates that the server starts, as the output is:

```
[10:33:56] 1 false
[10:33:56] 2 true
```

But if I go to `localhost:3005` after the gulp tasks are done, I can't see any server running. What might be the reason?

Comment: Could it be that calling `portInUse` for the second time, tries to start a second instance of the server on the same port and therefore ends in an error? The first instance being started with `run(args)`.

Comment: You cannot run "deamon" like task (which are constantly running) with gulp. You just need to run these tools separatly from a different console in general. However for this particular use case there is a gulp wrapper exists: https://github.com/GrafGenerator/gulp-json-server/ this tasks mimics the watch mode and handles the json changes and "restarts" the json server automatically

Comment: Thank you nemesv. Will try that. Now afk.

Comment: @nemesv you can write that as the answer and you'll get the bounty